# jQuery validate keeps getting a TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-validate

I'm implementing form validation in a Wordpress site using jQuery validate. I implemented this a bunch of time, but this time I can't get it to work. I include scripts in my `<head>` section like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?=get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js'?>"></script>
```

This is the right way to do it, right? First I'm including the jQuery library, then jQuery validate and finally I add my custom javascript where I call the validate method. This is the code I use for that:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    if($('#get-email').length > 0)
    {
        $('#get-email').validate();
    }

});
```

I don't see anything going wrong up to this point. But still I can't seem to get rid of a TypeError:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function
```

Does anyone know where this could be going wrong?

Keep in mind:

- This is a wordpress site
- I'm using bootstrap CSS and JS

Comment: please check whether your website loading multiple version of `jQuery` ???

Comment: Seemingly, this is not the problem. jQuery is actually loaded and accessible in custom.js.

Comment: WordPress loads a version of jQuery from wp-includes/js/jquery - sometimes it does cause conflicts. Try using `jQuery` instead of `$`

Comment: I did not know that! I removed my own include of jquery and moved other includes to the footer, and what do you know, problem solved! Something to keep in mind for wordpress developers I'd say.

Comment: `if ($('#get-email').length > 0)` is pointless.  You do not need to test for the existence of the element before attaching it. jQuery simply ignores non-existant elements without an error.